# SQL Design Relationship - Many to Many resolution

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, database-schema

I have a table relationship that I can't seem to resolve down to one to many and I'm wondering if anyone can offer some advice.

This is a case study that I'm working on for school. The database is being written for a television broadcasting company (similar to say a Comcast, DirecTV, etc...). Most of my tables are fine, with the exception of the programming tables. Here is the progression I currently have.

One program can play on one or more channels.
One channel can more play one or more programs. (There are a total of 10 channels)
One channel type can consist of one or more channels. (There are a two of 5 types, with 2 specific channels assigned to each type).
One programming package can consist of one or more channels (or channel types).
One channel (or channel type) can appear in one or more programming packages.

The way I currently have this put together is like this:

```
Programs ->-----|-- Channel Type --|-----< Channel --????----Program Package
-progid (PK)          -chtypeid (PK)        -chnumber (PK)       -pkgid (PK) 
-progname             -chtypedesc           -chtypeid (FK)      - pkgname
-progdesc                                                        -price
-chtypeid (FK)
```

The problem I'm running into is between Program Package and Channel. I can't seem to find an associative table that works between the two.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough. I'd post a pic of my current ERD, but apparently my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Can anyone offer some advice on what I might be missing??

Thanks.

Comment: You don't say that you are trying to find a way to express some particular table meaning in terms of given ones. Or what that meaning *is*. Or what the *given* meanings are. When you write "One program can play on one or more channels", what does that have to do with the tables? Does one of them contain rows where "program [p] can play on channel [c]"? (A: No.) Does one maybe contain rows where "program [p] can play on channel of channel type [t]"? Maybe, Programs? You don't say. We can't read your mind. What do we do with this arity constraint? Is it for some *new* meaning & table?

Answer (score 1):

Each present & absent row makes a statement. Just write the statement templates you need to describe your application situations.

A table has an associated parameterized statement (*proposition*) template (*predicate*). Table columns are template parameters. The rows that make the template into a true statement are the ones in the table. The other/absent rows make a false statement. All the currently present and absent rows of all the tables together describe the current situation.

```
Programs(progid,progname,progdesc,chtypeid) -- program [programid] named [progname] with description [progdesc] has channel type [chtypeid]
ChannelType(chtypeid,chtypedesc) -- channel type [chtypeid] has description [chtypedesc]
Channel(chnumber,chtypeid) -- channel [chnumber] is of type [chtypeid]
ProgramPackage(pkgid,pkname,price) -- programming package [pkgid] named [pkgname] costs $[price]
-- keys and fks straightforward
```

The templates and what situations can arise determine the constraints. (But one can't infer the templates, or what other templates are needed, from the constraints.)

Observe that the arity constraints below are given *in terms of the templates of the "association tables" that you can't find*.

> One program can play on one or more channels.

```
plays(progid,chnumber) -- program [progid] plays on channel [chnumber]
-- 2 fks 
-- plays progid:chnumber is many:many or 1:many
```

> One channel can more play one or more programs.

```
-- plays progid:chnumber is many:many or many:1
-- so (per the previous comment) it's many:many
-- so pk (progid,chnumber)
```

> (There are a total of 10 channels)

```
-- COUNT(Channels) = 10
-- [is this a constraint, or a certain situation?]
```

> One channel type can consist of one or more channels.

```
CTContainsCh(chtypeid,chnumber) -- channel type [chtypeid] contains channel [chnumber]
-- 2 fks
-- CTContainsCh chtypeid:chnumber is many:many or 1:many
-- so not pk (chtypeid)
```

> (There are a two of 5 types, with 2 specific channels assigned to each type).

```
-- [is this a constraint, or a certain situation?]
```

> One programming package can consist of one or more channels (or channel types).

```
PPContainsCh(pkgid,chnumber) -- programming package [pkgid] contains channel [chnumber]
-- 2 fks
-- PPContainsCh pkgid:chnumber is many:many or 1:many

PPContainsCT(pkgid,chtypeid) -- programming package [pkgid] contains channel type [chtypeid]
-- 2 fks
-- PPContainsCT pkgid:chtypeid is many:many or 1:many
```

> One channel (or channel type) can appear in one or more programming
>   packages.

```
-- PPContainsCh pkgid:chnumber is many:many or many:1
-- so (per the previous comment) it's many:many
-- so pk (pkgid,chnumber)

-- PPContainsCT pkgid:chtypeid is many:many or many:1
-- so (per the previous comment) it's many:many
-- so pk (pkgid,chnumber)

-- probably you intend PPContainsCT(pkgid,chtypeid) == EXISTS chnumber [ PPContainsCh(pkgid,chnumber) AND CTContainsCh(chtypeid,chnumber)]
-- ie PPContainsCT = (PPContainsCh JOIN CTContainsCh) PROJECT_OUT chnumber
-- so it's a view
-- nb its pkgid:chtypeid many:many nature follows from its definition
```

I'll leave you to think about what "can" contributes. Is it supposed to be saying that an entity can also be associated with 0 others?

> The problem I'm running into is between Program Package and Channel. I
>   can't seem to find an associative table that works between the two.

You have things backwards. First find the statement templates. Each template gives a table. Templates plus situations give constraints. (We then might combine, decompose and/or drop tables and/or constraints.)

PS: A program has a channel type. So presumably the channels it plays on are to be of that channel type, etc. Your question didn't mention this aspect of what it means for a program to "have a (permitted?)" channel type, for a program "to (be permitted to?) play on" a channel or for a channel type or programming package to "contain a (permitted?)" channel.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a junction table between `Program Package` and `Channel`

I would do something like

```
CREATE TABLE PackageChannels(
    pkgid VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES PROGRAMPACKAGE (pkgid),
    chnumber VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES CHANNEL (chnumber),
    PRIMARY KEY (pkgid, chnumber)
)
```

Not knowing what flavor of SQL you are using the syntax could be off. But answer is **Junction Table**

Also, welcome to SO.

Comment: We had this kind junction table in there to begin with, but the professor for the class rejected it, saying that it wasn't needed and that the associations could be worked out with the existing tables. The queries I needed to do worked with this type of junction, but clearly it's not what he was looking for.

Comment: Are you restricted to only the four tables you listed earlier?

Comment: No. I only listed the tables that were directly associated with the problem I was having. There are 11 or 12 tables total in the database, if I recall correctly. But the ones listed are the only ones in the Program to Type to Channel to Package relationship line.

Comment: Okay so the expectation from your Professor is that you can establish the described relationships without anything additional.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider stating that a program package consists of only channel types. Each channel type consists of one or more channels and a channel shows one or more programs; multiple channels of different channel types can show the same program.

If a channel must be part of a channel type, you don't have a (direct) relationship between program package and channel.

Comment: This, I think, is the key to the problem. Moving channel type between channel and package and expanding the records in channel type should make it work. Currently I have ten records inserted in channel type (one type for each channel..example chtypeid 501 = channel 1). But if I expand that to one record in channel type for each instance of a channel within a package, then I think the queries will work.(example chtypeid "pkgname"501 = channel 1).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, you need the following additional association tables.

```
Program_Channel(progid(FK),chnumber(FK)) : Association between program and channel
Channel_ChannelType(chnumber(FK),chtypeid(FK)) : Association between channel and channeltype
Channel_ChannelPackage(chnumber(FK),pkgid(FK)) : Association between channel and channel package
```

With this you can have many to many relationship with all the above entities

Comment: Currently the records in Program contain a "chnum" FK that links to the Channel table. So progid has a link to the Channel table. Is there some reason that this wouldn't work or are we just talking a difference in writing styles??

Comment: According to your description, there is n to n relationship between program and channel. In that case chnum cannot be in Program table, this link has to be moved to the association table.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you need a many to many relationship between Program Package and Channel.

Add a chtypeid(FK) to Program Package and you will have a many to many relationship between Program Package and Channel over the ChannelType.

```
Programs Package >-----|------ Channel Type ------|-----< Channel 
-pkgid (PK)                    -chtypeid (PK)             -chnumber (PK)        
-pkgname                       -chtypedesc                -chtypeid (FK)       
-price                                                         
-chtypeid(FK)
```